# Is there a way to access the children of an astro slot?

Tags: astrojs

I am trying to use an astro slot to pass children to a SolidJS component. My Solid component uses its children to generate slides.

```
<Slider>
  {props.children}
</Slider>
```

The problem is that when I try to do this, the children I pass to the component are wrapped with an `<astro-slot>`, so my component only "sees" one child. Is there a way to properly access the children of the slot, or to remove the wrapper tag altogether?

Answer (score 1):

[Passing Children to Framework Components](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/#passing-children-to-framework-components)

You can use named slots to split the child elements up like this

```
// src/pages/index.astro

<Slider>
  <div slot="1"></div>
  <div slot="2"></div>
  <div slot="3"></div>
</Slider>
```

Then you can access the named slots using `props`

```
// src/components/Slider.tsx

export default function Slider(props) {            
    return (
        <>
            {props.1}
            {props.2}
            {props.3}
        </>
    );
}
```